# Why does the recalculation of the form drop the first javascript calculation?

Tags: javascript, forms

I am trying to recalculate the form based on a payment method. What I have is sort of working. It fails however if the payment method is changed after entering the number of widgets needed. The widget 2 value stays intact but the widget 1 calculation reverts to 0 yet the entered number is still in the number of widgets needed for Widget 1.

```js
function lf(vntAmount) {
  vntAmount = parseFloat(vntAmount) || 0; // find number (parseFloat) switch it to 0 if not a number
  vntAmount = vntAmount * 100; // cost of widget 1
  document.frmConvert.box1.value = vntAmount.toFixed(2)
}

function rf(vntAmount) {
  vntAmount = parseFloat(vntAmount) || 0; // find number (parseFloat)
  vntAmount = vntAmount * 200; // cost of widget 2
  document.frmConvert.box2.value = vntAmount.toFixed(2)
}

function calculate() {
  var myBox1 = document.getElementById('box1').value;
  var myBox2 = document.getElementById('box2').value;
  //  var result = document.getElementById('result');  // don't know what this does
  if (document.getElementById('visa_checked').checked) {
    var myResult = (parseFloat(myBox1) + parseFloat(myBox2)) * .15;
  } else {
    var myResult = (parseFloat(myBox1) + parseFloat(myBox2)) * .12;
  }
  var myResult2 = myResult + (parseFloat(myBox1) + parseFloat(myBox2));
  result.value = myResult.toFixed(2);
  result2.value = '$' + myResult2.toFixed(2);
}
```

```css
body {
  font-family: arial;
  font-size: 100%;
  color: #aea2a2
}
```

```html
<html>

<head>
  <title>Test Form</title>
  <script type="text/javascript">
    onload = function() {
      location.href = "#";
    }
  </script>
</head>

<body>
  <FORM ACTION="processform.php" METHOD=POST name="frmConvert">

    <h4>Widgets For Sale</h4>
    Mandatory field *<br><br> Name*
    <br>
    <input type="text" name="sheetdata[]" size="42"><br><br> Address
    <br>
    <input type="text" name="sheetdata[]" size="42"><br><br> City
    <br>
    <input type="text" name="sheetdata[]" size="42"><br><br> Postal Code<br>
    <input type="text" name="sheetdata[]" size="42"><br><br> Email
    <br>
    <input type="text" name="sheetdata[]" size="42"><br><br> Phone*
    <br>
    <input type="text" name="sheetdata[]" size="42"><br><br> Method of payment<br>
    <input type="radio" name="sheetdata[]" value="Visa" id="visa_checked" onChange="lf(this.value);calculate();">Visa<br>
    <input type="radio" name="sheetdata[]" value="Cheque" onChange="lf(this.value);calculate();">Cheque<br>
    <input type="radio" name="sheetdata[]" value="E-Transfer" onChange="lf(this.value);calculate();" checked>E Transfer<br>
    <br><br> Number of Widget One needed:<br>
    <input name="sheetdata[]" id="txtAmount" type="text" value="" onchange="lf(this.value);calculate();" size="3" value="0" /> @ $100 <input name="sheetdata[]" size="5" readonly="readonly" id="box1" value="0" />
    <br><br> Number of Widget Two needed<br>
    <input name="sheetdata[]" id="txtAmount2" type="text" value="" onChange="rf(this.value);calculate();" size="3" value="0" /> @ $200 <input name="sheetdata[]" size="5" readonly="readonly" id="box2" value="0" />
    <br><br> Tax 12% <input name="sheetdata[]" id="result" size="5" readonly="readonly" /> 3 % added for Credit Card
    <br><br> Total <input name="sheetdata[]" id="result2" size="5" readonly="readonly" />

    <input type="hidden" name="sheet_name" value="Test_Form">

    <p><input type="submit" value="Submit" name="B1"><input type="reset" value="Reset" name="B2"></p>
    <p>Thank You!</p>
  </form>

</body>

</html>
```

Not sure what to try to fix this.

Comment: The argument to `lf()` has to be a number. What are you expecting `lf(this.value)` to do when the radio button has `value="Visa"`?

Comment: I want the form to recalculate the tax field, which it does when the payment method is changed. The problen is though, the widget 1 calculation goes to 0 when the form is recalculated.

Comment: The reason is because you do `vntAmount = parseFloat(vntAmount) || 0`. Since `parseFloat(vntAmount)` returns `NaN`, this sets `vntAmount` to `0`. Then you get 0 when you multiply.

Comment: So why does it only happen for the widget one calculation but  not to widget 2?

Comment: Because you set widget one value in `lf()` and widget two value in `rf()`. You never call `rf()` with a non-number value.

Comment: It looks like `lf()` should always use the `txtAmount` value, not the value of the dropdown.

Comment: It took me a while... but I see what you mean, I removed the lf on the radio buttons and now it works as expected. Thanks for the help.